# Spring, MVC and REST in two servlets

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, servlets

**Long story short:**
I have MVC servlet that handles requests correctly, but REST servlet seems to never handle any request, at all. Like it was not there, or requests are somehow not matched.

**In more details:**

My spring version is 4.2.1.

I have an application with Spring MVC, which already works. Problem is a second servlet, that I want to add, so it would handle REST requests.

This was the `web.xml` **before** I tried to add REST servlet into it (so everything worked here so far):

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
     http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">

    <display-name>My app</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/core-context.xml /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>AccServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.do</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>RestServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

In few words - all requests to `*.do` will be handled by MVC servlet, all requests in general will pass through Spring Security.

I have a simple MVC controller to handle that:

```
@Controller
public class JspController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/index.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String provideIndexModel(ModelMap model) {
        User user = userService.getLoggedUser();
        model.addAttribute("user", user.getUsername());
        if (user.getBusiness() != null) {
            model.addAttribute("business", user.getBusiness().getCompanyName());
        }
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login.do", method = {RequestMethod.GET})
    public String provideLoginModel(ModelMap model) {
        return "login";
    }

    public UserService getUserService() {
        return userService;
    }

    public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }
}
```

The controller is in package scanned by proper scan declaration in servlet's context xml file.

Now, what I did to enable REST was to add following servlet to `web.xml`:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>AccServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RestServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.rest</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Then I created another servlet context file `RestServlet-servlet.xml`, where I put `<context:component-scan base-package="my.app.rest"/>` - that's the package, where I then put a RestController, like this:

```
@RestController
public class RestService {

    public RestService() {
        System.out.println("yes!");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user.rest", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getUser() {
        return "abc";
    }
}
```

The rest controller indeed is created (I debugged the constructor), so spring does see it, but when I try to call it from the Postman (Chrome extension), I get 404 response. My request is for URL: `localhost:8080/acc/user.rest` (where `acc` is my app name).

Why my calls matching `*.rest` do not get redirected to proper controller? (I tried to stop there in debug - it's never called).

**EDIT 1:**

This is my current full web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <display-name>My app</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/core-context.xml /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>AccServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.do</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>AccServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>RestServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>RestServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

This is my core-context.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd   
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="my.app">
        <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"
            type="annotation" />
    </context:component-scan>

    <bean id="accDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/acc" />
        <property name="username" value="acc" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="accSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="accDataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>my.app.entities</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <value>
                hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL92Dialect
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="txManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="accSessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />

</beans>
```

This is AccServlet-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="my.app.web"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

This my RestServlet-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="my.app.rest"/>

</beans>
```

I have `@Controller` for MVC in `my.app.web` and I have `@RestController` in `my.app.rest`.

Logs from tomcat:

```
20-Oct-2015 14:00:16.096 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.23
20-Oct-2015 14:00:16.097 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          May 19 2015 14:58:38 UTC
20-Oct-2015 14:00:16.097 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.23.0
20-Oct-2015 14:00:16.097 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
20-Oct-2015 14:00:16.097 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            3.14.33
20-Oct-2015 14:00:16.097 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
20-Oct-2015 14:00:16.097 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib64/java/jre
20-Oct-2015 14:00:16.097 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_45-b14
20-Oct-2015 14:00:16.097 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
20-Oct-2015 14:00:16.098 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
20-Oct-2015 14:00:16.174 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
20-Oct-2015 14:00:16.183 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
20-Oct-2015 14:00:16.184 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
20-Oct-2015 14:00:16.185 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
20-Oct-2015 14:00:16.185 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 297 ms
20-Oct-2015 14:00:16.200 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
20-Oct-2015 14:00:16.200 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.23
20-Oct-2015 14:00:16.213 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive /home/googie/projects/tomcat/webapps/acc.war
20-Oct-2015 14:00:16.951 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
20-Oct-2015 14:00:16.968 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
20-Oct-2015 14:00:17.012 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.prepareRefresh Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Oct 20 14:00:17 CEST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
20-Oct-2015 14:00:17.031 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/core-context.xml]
20-Oct-2015 14:00:17.149 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml]
20-Oct-2015 14:00:17.176 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.security.core.SpringSecurityCoreVersion.performVersionChecks You are running with Spring Security Core 4.0.2.RELEASE
20-Oct-2015 14:00:17.178 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.security.config.SecurityNamespaceHandler.<init> Spring Security 'config' module version is 4.0.2.RELEASE
20-Oct-2015 14:00:17.197 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.security.config.http.FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSourceParser.parseInterceptUrlsForFilterInvocationRequestMap Creating access control expression attribute 'hasRole('ROLE_USER')' for /**
20-Oct-2015 14:00:17.231 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.security.config.http.HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser.checkFilterChainOrder Checking sorted filter chain: [Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 200, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 400, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 500, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 700, <org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0>, order = 1100, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1500, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1600, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1700, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1900, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 2000, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 2100, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 2200, <org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0>, order = 2300]
20-Oct-2015 14:00:17.489 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.Version.logVersion HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.2.Final}
20-Oct-2015 14:00:17.490 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.<clinit> HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
20-Oct-2015 14:00:17.491 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.buildBytecodeProvider HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
20-Oct-2015 14:00:17.521 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager.<clinit> HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.0.Final}
20-Oct-2015 14:00:17.613 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.<init> HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL92Dialect
20-Oct-2015 14:00:17.704 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl.useContextualLobCreation HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
20-Oct-2015 14:00:17.705 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry.register HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@43d414e2
20-Oct-2015 14:00:18.117 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.afterPropertiesSet Using DataSource [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@4c992a74] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
20-Oct-2015 14:00:18.130 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain.<init> Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/lib/**'], []
20-Oct-2015 14:00:18.132 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain.<init> Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/plugins/**'], []
20-Oct-2015 14:00:18.133 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain.<init> Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/dist/**'], []
20-Oct-2015 14:00:18.134 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain.<init> Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/bootstrap/**'], []
20-Oct-2015 14:00:18.135 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain.<init> Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/css/**'], []
20-Oct-2015 14:00:18.136 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain.<init> Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/fonts/**'], []
20-Oct-2015 14:00:18.137 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain.<init> Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/login*'], []
20-Oct-2015 14:00:18.270 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain.<init> Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@4a5281b8, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@42066dde, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@7fda7a84, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@67125593, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@39134788, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@488ab5e9, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@6428f826, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@116387fd, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter@32efbd5e, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@2f576317, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@c9d5713, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@14c7512, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@4e063d28]
20-Oct-2015 14:00:18.277 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.security.config.http.DefaultFilterChainValidator.checkLoginPageIsntProtected Checking whether login URL '/login.do' is accessible with your configuration
20-Oct-2015 14:00:18.297 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1329 ms
20-Oct-2015 14:00:18.320 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initServletBean FrameworkServlet 'AccServlet': initialization started
20-Oct-2015 14:00:18.322 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.prepareRefresh Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'AccServlet-servlet': startup date [Tue Oct 20 14:00:18 CEST 2015]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
20-Oct-2015 14:00:18.322 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/AccServlet-servlet.xml]
20-Oct-2015 14:00:18.369 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.registerHandler Mapped URL path [/index.do] onto handler 'jspController'
20-Oct-2015 14:00:18.369 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.registerHandler Mapped URL path [/login.do] onto handler 'jspController'
20-Oct-2015 14:00:18.517 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initServletBean FrameworkServlet 'AccServlet': initialization completed in 197 ms
20-Oct-2015 14:00:18.517 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initServletBean FrameworkServlet 'RestServlet': initialization started
20-Oct-2015 14:00:18.518 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.prepareRefresh Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'RestServlet-servlet': startup date [Tue Oct 20 14:00:18 CEST 2015]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
20-Oct-2015 14:00:18.518 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/RestServlet-servlet.xml]
20-Oct-2015 14:00:18.539 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.registerHandler Mapped URL path [/rest/user] onto handler 'restService'
20-Oct-2015 14:00:18.539 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.registerHandler Mapped URL path [/rest/user.*] onto handler 'restService'
20-Oct-2015 14:00:18.539 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.registerHandler Mapped URL path [/rest/user/] onto handler 'restService'
20-Oct-2015 14:00:18.545 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initServletBean FrameworkServlet 'RestServlet': initialization completed in 28 ms
20-Oct-2015 14:00:18.552 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive /home/googie/projects/tomcat/webapps/acc.war has finished in 2,338 ms
20-Oct-2015 14:00:18.552 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /home/googie/projects/tomcat/webapps/manager
20-Oct-2015 14:00:18.569 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /home/googie/projects/tomcat/webapps/manager has finished in 17 ms
20-Oct-2015 14:00:18.571 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
20-Oct-2015 14:00:18.578 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
20-Oct-2015 14:00:18.579 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 2394 ms
20-Oct-2015 14:00:37.639 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-8] org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator.initiateService HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
20-Oct-2015 14:00:50.965 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/acc/rest/user] in DispatcherServlet with name 'RestServlet'
```

Note, that the last line in log comes from my GET request try to the rest service.

Comment: Your web.xml is Servlet 2.3 targeted, so chances are that many things run in fallback compatibility modus even when your target container is of a newer version. Get rid of the doctype and upgrade the `<web-app>` declaration to match the latest supported by your target container (Tomcat 6 = Servlet 2.5, Tomcat 7 = Servlet 3.0, Tomcat 8 = Servlet 3.1) then retry.

Comment: Good point. I've fixed it (to version 3.1), but the core problem remains.

Comment: An interesting things started to appear in tomcat log as I upgraded to servlet 3.1. Now it prints on startup: `Mapped URL path [/acc/rest/user] onto handler 'restService'` but later on when I call the rest path I see in logs: `org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/acc/rest/user] in DispatcherServlet with name 'RestServlet'`. I've playied with several mappings (with `/acc` included in front, without it, etc - nothing works unfortunately).

Comment: Try /*.rest/* in the mapping.

Comment: I believe you suppose to have `<mvc:annotation-driven>` in your app context xml but seems you might have missed it.

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem. It turned out that both *-servlet.xml context files should have `<mvc:annotation-driven />` declaration in order to have controllers working properly. Without it the servlet worked, but mappings were not handled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me the difference in the servlet name in servlet definition and mapping(`<servlet-name>RestServlet</servlet-name>` and `<servlet-name>AccServlet</servlet-name>`) is causing the problem.

You are naming the dispatcher servlet **AccServlet** and providing the mapping for  **RestServlet** will not work.

In spring-mvc all delegation is done by `DispatcherServlet`.A possible combination would be:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/core-context.xml /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>AccServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AccServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Then your RESt controller could be like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest")
public class RestService {
}
```

All your rest clients would user URl of the pattern `http://ip:port/yourapp/rest/something`
The MVC controller could be:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/mvc")
public class JspController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/index.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String provideIndexModel(ModelMap model) {
      User user = userService.getLoggedUser();
      model.addAttribute("user", user.getUsername());
      if (user.getBusiness() != null) {
          model.addAttribute("business",   user.getBusiness().getCompanyName());
      }
      return "index";
  }
}
```

Use the URL of the pattern `localhost:8080/acc/mvc/index.do` for MVC stuff.

Comment: I've tried that and now none of them work. Neither mvc, nor rest. 
Both return 404. I've tried to open `http://ip:port/yourapp/mvc/`, `http://ip:port/yourapp/` and `http://ip:port/yourapp/mvc/index.do` - with no success.

Comment: And also I was not doing 2 mappings for single servlet - please notice I have 2 servlets declared and they have a single mapping defined for each of them.

Comment: I can't see the 2 servlets. COuld you share consolidated web.xml? Also, i have updated the URL that should be working with my suggested configuration. Are you using an rest client/tool?

Comment: Also, could you update your question with the log statement?

Comment: I've added all info you asked for (together with context files). Regarding two servlets - I have two servlets defined "AccServlet" and "RestServlet" - each with its own declaration in `<servlet>` and own mapping defined in `<servlet-mapping>`.

Comment: Oh - and about the URL, I figured out that it should have been `acc` instead of `yourapp`. I tried it with `acc` back then and it didn't work.

Comment: And have you provided appropriate annotations on each controller class as mentioned in my answer?